# bash, can't grep root partition from df using \< \>

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

OS: FreeBSD 8.2, bash

Hey guys,

I'm stumped as to why I can't grep the the line with / partition from df:

```
/dev/amrd0s1a    1012974    452694     479244    49%    /
```

I want to be able to grep that line only, (other lines have slashes too) so I figured one of these would work:

```
df -m | grep -E '\<'/'\>' 

df -m | grep -E '\</\>' 

df -m | grep -E '\<"/"\>'
```

but neither of those work, I was wanting to do it this way so I could practice using the '\< \>'. I tried with out the -E as well.

Can this be done? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\<` and `\>` are for word boundaries, but `/` is not a word character. Instead match the preceding whitespace and following EOL: `[[:space:]]/$`.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
df -m | grep "/$"
```

$  means end of line

Comment: This is a clean one, I'll use this one. Thanks!

Comment: @jonschipp This assumes that there is no other line which is terminated with `/`. But, that's the case with `df` command, so it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just specifying / as parameter?

```
  df -m /
```

to strip off the headline:

```
  df -m / | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get this line using the following:

```
df -m | grep " \+/$"
```

Comment: Does `\+` work in the BSD grep? I think it might be a GNU extension to BREs. (Not that it matters, it could be omitted without a problem from the regex.)

Comment: You don't really care how many spaces there are, as long as there is one adjacent to the slash. So `' /$'` is really a better regex, and compatible with traditional grep.